# install hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

tried to install Hadoop cluster

```
OS Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
Ambari Version 2.5.1.0
HDP 2.6
```

App Timeline Server Install returned error:

```
2018-02-26 19:31:49,406 - Installing package hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs')
2018-02-26 19:31:51,614 - Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs' returned 1. Error: Package: hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs-2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129.x86_64 (HDP-2.6)
```

Tried to exceute command on server:

```
 /usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs
Error: Package: hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs-2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129.x86_64 (HDP-2.6)
           Requires: libtirpc-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Tried to find libtirpc-devel

```
yum search libtirpc
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
=============================================================================================== N/S matched: libtirpc ===============================================================================================
libtirpc.i686 : Transport Independent RPC Library
libtirpc.x86_64 : Transport Independent RPC Library
```

installed

```
 yum install libtirpc.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Package libtirpc-0.2.4-0.10.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Tried to install more time and returned again error:

```
/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs
Error: Package: hadoop_2_6_1_0_129-hdfs-2.7.3.2.6.1.0-129.x86_64 (HDP-2.6)
           Requires: libtirpc-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What else can you try to do?

Comment: Did you look at https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/96763/hdp-26-ambari-install-fails-on-rhel-7-on-libtirpc.html - "Ambari 2.5 deploy of hdp 2.6 faiils on RHEL 7 on libtirpc-devel libarary
"?

Comment: Did look issue by url. Did execute sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
sudo yum install libtirpc-devel. Problem reproduced again.

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qa |grep tirpc`?

Comment: rpm -qa |grep tirpc
libtirpc-0.2.4-0.10.el7.x86_64
libtirpc-0.2.4-0.10.el7.i686

Comment: You're still missing libtirpc-devel.  You can download the RPM directly via https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/libtirpc-devel-0.2.4-0.10.el7.x86_64.rpm then do `rpm -i RPM_FILE` as root but the other way should have worked.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using Ambari to install HDP?

Comment: Install this package solved problem with libtirpc-devel - sudo yum install http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/software/mirror/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/Packages/libtirpc-devel-0.2.4-0.10.el7.x86_64.rpm